# Action Bar icon size

Tags: android, icons, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

According to [Action Bar Icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar.html#size11) action bar icon for the mdpi screen should be 24 x 24 px but the icons in [Action Bar Icon Pack](https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html) for mdpi are 32 x 32 px. The sizes do not match for other screen sizes neither. So which one is correct and what dimensions should the action bar icon have?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**UPDATE: this answer is no longer valid, see the below answer for more up-to-date guidelines.**

I believe they have to be 32x32dp, but the actual image itself should be 24dpx24dp centred. The Android design website has the [correct guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#action-bar).

I've submitted a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29295&q=icon%20size&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) about this but have yet to hear anything...

Comment: I guess you meant px and not dp?

Comment: `dp` means device independent pixel, the unit that's usually used in the Android UI.

Comment: Is this answer obsolete?

Comment: This answer is obsolete. The new guidelines are 24x24dp image (file). This is made of 20x20 content in center with 2dp padding to each side (4dp in total).

Answer (score 55):

-------update 2015.10.17--------

[The new google design gideline](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-system-icons) says:"System icons are displayed at 24dp","Icon content is limited to the 20 x 20dp live area, with 4px of trim around the perimeter".Like:

[image]
------old-------

[Full asset, 32x32 dp;
Optical square, 24x24 dp](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#action-bar)

[image]

Comment: I guess you meant px and not dp?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka it is dp as stated in the documentation (in the link).

Comment: What does dp mean when you use icon editing tools? A pixel is a squarish unit that has one color. It has a meaning. Look at the documentation for the meaning of **baseline**.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka dp are density-independent pixels. it's a scale for actual pixels. mdpi is the baseline, so 24dp in mdpi is 24px. For hdpi devices, the scale is 1.5x, so 24dp is 36px.

Comment: Full asset size has changed from 32dp to 48dp with Material (Android 5)

Answer (score 15):

I've conducted more testing with AppCompat ActionBar. I found out, that the ActionBar takes care for itself to enforce the minimum 48dp touch target size. I also found out, that the AppCompat ActionBar still expects action bar icons with a 32dp square size.

**Even with Material design, icons still have to follow rule "Full asset: 32x32 dp; Optical square: 24x24 dp" to have the correct size along with other icons in the action bar** as this figure (from wangqi060934's anwer) shows:

[image]

**My previous assumption (see figures below) that the full asset size expanded from 32dp to 48dp is not correct.** The 48dp are talking about the touch area. The confusion was caused by the revised [Material Icon Spec document](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#) which is linked in the much older [ActionBar document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems).

[image]

from https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-system-icons

[image]

from http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-sizing-by-increments

Comment: The area in blue/pink is "Clearance area","Adequate space around the icon is needed to allow for legibility and touch.",as the guideline said.

Comment: The [Material Design icons](https://design.google.com/icons/) provided by Google do not give an option to download 32dp icons. What's going on here?

Answer (score 14):

Use Android Studio Image Asset

Go to:

1. Project>res --> right click
2. new> image asset --> Icon type: Action Bar and Tab Icons
3. next>Finish.

Now you will have your icon in the correct resolutions.

Comment: just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

The finished action bar icon dimensions as shown in the link below should be.
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar.html

Low density screen

```
ldpi (120 dpi) --> 18 x 18 px
```

Medium density screen

```
mdpi (160 dpi) --> 24 x 24 px
```

High density screen

```
hdpi (240 dpi) --> 36 x 36 px
```

Extra-high density screen

```
xhdpi (320 dpi) --> 48 x 48 px
```

XX-high density screen

```
xxhdpi (480 dpi) --> 72 x 72 px
```

XXX-high density screen

```
xxxhdpi (640 dpi) --> 96 x 96 px
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for was the pixel size I needed so I size down copies of my image as needed for each folder. There is now also xxhdpi and xxx. These are created in some project by default so I will suggest an edit/update to your post to add those as well.