# Action bar icon size

Tags: android, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Action Bar icon size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244918/action-bar-icon-size)

Android has conflicting information about what size icons to use in the action bar.

- [they say 32dp here](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html)
- [they say 36dp here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar.html)

Does anyone know which is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm wow looks like they indeed made a mistake. You might want to take a look at the google icon generator which comes with the adt 20. Look which size it generates, this should be right.

Comment: How did this get migrated *from* android?

Answer (score 0):

32dp is the correct value.
I accessed [the site with 36dp](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar.html) today and I saw 36px (maybe Google has corrected the value).