# How big should Action Bar(Toolbar) icons be in the new Android Material design?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I tried searching the design guidelines, but I couldn't find anything related to this. I am trying to figure out the optimal size for Action bar icons in the new L release. Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: screenshot]

I tried the previous 48dp size, but it looks a lot bigger than the ones in that picture.

Comment: Are you using Drawable images of all the various DPIs? The Android system should automatically select the one of optimal size based on the device's screen resolution if you have provided multiple resources for each Drawable in the appropriate resource folders

Comment: I was creating generic icons from the assets studio.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

From [Material Design Keylines Touch Target Size](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-touch-target-size), size for icons is `24dp`

Comment: oh no. Not the action bar size, but the icons that go in that bar. Like the search icon and overflow icon.

Comment: Whoops. Right page, wrong topic: I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @ianhanniballake do you mean png file should be 24dp size without inner paddings for icon?

Comment: @AlexKorovyansky - correct. 24dp optical bounds such as the `_24dp` versions found on the [material design icon repository](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons). Just keep in mind the minimum 48dp touch target size (Toolbar/AppCompat should do this automatically so no need to worry about those cases).

Comment: I just wanted to mention something is not quite right here, the 24dp icons Google provide in the repo do not match what they themselves are using in official apps -- they seem to use something with more padding

Comment: @DanielWilson Yes, they look ridiculously oversized if you just paste them in from the repo.

Comment: Could you provide an example of an ImageButton in XML displaying this correct size and touch target?

Comment: I think it's ok that the canvas size and the content itself would be the same : 24dp. This is what the Android assets Studio produces too: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=3d_rotation&source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_action_3d_rotation&theme=light&color=rgba(33%2C%20150%2C%20243%2C%200.6)

Answer (score 4):

Full icon size should be `24dp` with a "live" area of `20dp`.
See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14908467/3979479