# Android navigation drawer hamburger height and width

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, hamburger-menu

[hamburger icon in toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x70a1.png)

how to set height and width of this icon?
i have attached the screenshot,
following is my code for setting this custom icon:

```
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this , drawer , toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open , R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menu_white);
    toggle.syncState();
    toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
            {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
            else
            {
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        }
    });
```

Anyone can suggest what to do in this situation?

Comment: what is the height and width of that icon?

Comment: width is 65 and height is 38 @Aditya Vyas-Lakhan

Comment: try this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874175/what-is-the-recommended-actionbar-icon-size-in-material-design-android-api-21

Comment: thank you @M.Waqas Pervez but how to set this width is a issue like my cart icon for toolbar is 40 dp but how to set for this hamburger icon?

Comment: find `R.drawable.menu_white` in your drawable folder. resize it with some editor ...

Comment: Ok thank you @ M.Waqas Pervez

Comment: change the size of your icon