# ActionBar option icon not showing properly

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my ActionBar, I have only one option menu item, and it only has icon and no text.

[image]

The context menu icon and the logo are well aligned (center vertical) but the material tv icon (24d - 96x96) looks collapsed. I'm not able to figure out how to make it the exact height as the context menu icon's height. Here is the part of my AppBarLayout file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgToolbarLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/dunya_logo_white" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

The menu item is:

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_watch_live"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_tv_white"
    android:title=""
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Please help me how to central align this material icon like the Context Menu icon on the left.

Comment: I don't want to display the text. I just want the icon to appear nicely, centrally aligned (vertically), just like the context menu icon on the left.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html , icons for different densities

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your Image Drawable Folder not correct so, Try to Inset The Correct Image sizes in correct Drawable folder.can you refer the following links

http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/

[What is the recommended ActionBar icon size in Material Design (Android API 21+)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874175/what-is-the-recommended-actionbar-icon-size-in-material-design-android-api-21)

Comment: You were right, I hadn't added the icon using Android Studio's Add Image Asset tool which resizes the image according to the standard action bar menu icons. I added the image using 'Add Image Asset' wizard and my issue has been resolved, it automatically places the icons in their corresponding folders.