# How to set the height and width of navIcon in ToolbarAndroid of react-native?

Tags: android, react-native, android-toolbar

I am using `navIcon` of `ToolbarAndroid` to show the Icon in my `react-native` application as follows:

```
<ToolbarAndroid
    actions={[]}
    navIcon={require('./arrow-left-c.png')}
    onIconClicked={navigator.pop}
    style={{height:180,backgroundColor:'#a9a9a9'}}
    titleColor="white"
    title={route.name} />
```

But the problem is that the icon `arrow-left-c` is taking the whole width of screen. I only want to display it in the left side as normal icon appears. How can I set the width and height of this `navIcon`?

Comment: try to use `Icon.ToolbarAndroid`. ref here: `https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons`

Answer (score 1):

Currently you cannot set the size of navIcon in React native ToolBarAndroid.

Toolbar icon size should be 24dp as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25235955/2125612).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem,and i solved it.

we know we need the icon with 24dp,and we need rename file name end up with `@3X`,

such as `app_logo.png  ===>  app_logo@3x.png`

you can found this at [Images of RN](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html)

Answer (score -3):

It will be a better option if u use seprate layout for toolbar and then inflate it in toolbar.In this layout you will be able to give any style size color and icon to it.

Take a new xml file app_bar layout and copy the following code in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/back_font"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBtn"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnBack"
            android:text="Create Account"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBtn"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

then in your activity containing toolbar copy this code.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

final View barview =LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.app_bar_register, toolbar, false);
 toolbar.addView(barview);

 if (toolbar != null) {
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            }
ImageView btnBack= (ImageView) barview.findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            });
```

Comment: This question is for react-native.