# Toolbar navigation icon can't be center inside

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, scaletype

I want to set the navigation icon for my toolbar ,and get into the problem that **the icon isn't center inside by default** it looks like:

---

[image]

and the code is:

---

```
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true); 
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_48dp);
```

---

and the theme.xml is:

---

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
```

and the layout xml is:

---

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
/>
```

I think I have tried everything I know but I just can't figure it out.I used to set the navigation icon for toolbar then it will be center inside  and now.Any help will save my day!

Eidted: of course I tried different size of icons
[image: 24dp]
[image: 32dp]
and I konw I could add a custom layout in toolbar or customize a layout like (which is a Linearlayout I write about)

---

[image]

---

But I just don't why I can't set the navigation icon like before,it will automatically be center inside....I think maybe I should change the theme or define something like navigationButttonStyle in the attributes....

Comment: see thsi link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244918/action-bar-icon-size

Comment: May be your icon size is large. Here is the guide lines https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-product-icons

Comment: You should use 36 dp images .

Comment: why are you not usnig default navigation icon ?

Comment: whatever the size of the image is ,like 18 24 36 48 dp,it always fill the toolbar and its scale type  is center crop ,so the problem may be not the size of icon

Answer (score 1):

I fix this by inherit the right theme `Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar` rather than `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar` to define my own toolbar style.
And use

```
<item name="toolbarStyle">@style/MyToolBar</item>
```

to set the toolbarStyle

Comment: Thanks, the right answer, the navigation icon was too high positioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a bit big image. Try figure it out using this [link](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#)

Comment: This must be a comment ! Link can be vanish !

Answer (score -1):

OK now I finally find out where the problem is: **which has nothing to do with the icon size**

---

You should place the image resource in the to the corresponding folder like (drawable-xxhdpi , drawable-xhdpi).If you don't do so,*which means if you just put it in the drawable folder* , it won't be auto resized to be center inside in your toolbar;