# Menu item goes in dropdown list menu not in the action bar

Tags: android, android-menu

**Hello**

I'm trying to add 2 menu items in the action bar. On the designer they look ok, but when I run the application, both menu items goes in the dropdown list hamburger menu (there's enough "room" to display on the action bar).

I tried to replace `app:showAsAction` to `android:showAsAction`, doesn't work this replacement.

this is my **menu_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.tabdemo.MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="never"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/userMenu"
    android:title="User"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/logoutMenu"
    android:icon="@drawable/opendoorlogo2"
    android:title="Logout"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

And this is the java code:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem userMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.userMenu);
    userMenuItem.setTitle(username);// global string
    MenuItem logoutMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.logoutMenu);
    logoutMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.opendoorlogo2);
    return true;
}
```

Thanks in advance (P.S. Logo doesn't load on Logout menu Item)

Comment: Try setting `orderInCategory` for your items. Documentations states that most important items are show as action, and it may be that without the attribute, your items has no importance at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    First of all make sure your drawable file is not too big for the actionbar, if so you can convert it to actionbar icon size.
```

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_action_example&theme=light&color=33b5e5%2C60

```
android:showAsAction="always"

    if this doesn't help you. 

    Best way is to create a custom actionbar layout and place your icon over there instead of adding it as Menus.
```

Comment: Site doesn't work properly. The downloaded file isn't a zip or a archive filetype. Site goes in null exception errors . Thanks anyway.

Comment: The logo isn't the actual problem, I deleted the logo line code, I added always at showAsAction attribute, same problem :)

Comment: I Think i'll make a custom actionbar

Comment: But I still want to know the fix

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244918/action-bar-icon-size , this might help, better go for a custom actionbar, you can do whatever you want using it.

Comment: The problem is, I have already a custom bar, and use fragments, and tabs. that will be tricky